# Android: Implementar libreria Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, que cuando selecciono imágenes de mi clase `PictureActivity` las mando al `AsyncTask` que esta en mi clase UploadImage pero tambien directamente las estoy agregando al objeto de CheckIn (getImages) que esta en mi clase CheckIn y cuando termina ese proceso PictureActivity me manda a mi clase donde se muestran que es IndexActivity lo que pasa es que cuando selecciono la imagen para eliminarla, el AsyncTask aun no a terminado el proceso, estuve investigando la forma que cuando me lanze a mi actividad donde veo las imagenes(IndexActivity) el usuario visualize el proceso de carga de las imágenes y me encontré con la librería [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), quiero implementarla en mi aplicación pero tengo problemas al entender como hacerlo en mi codigo y no entiendo muy bien la documentacion, espero y me puedan ayudar.

> IndexActivity.java

```
CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//creo una instancia de CheckIn
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    if (checkIn.getImages().size() > 0) {//valido de que existan imagenes
        for (ImageData object: checkIn.getImages()) {
            bitmaps.add(object.getBitmap());//al ArrayList le agrego los Bitmaps
        }//for
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, bitmaps));//seteo las imagenes al gridView
    }//./if
```

> PictureActivity.java

```
CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//TODO YA NO

                    for (int i = 0; i < principalListOfImages.size(); i++) {
                        ImageData imageData = new ImageData();//creo una instancia de ImageData
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(principalListOfImages.get(i));//paso el path a Bitmap
                        imageData.setBitmap(bitmap);//le setteo el bitmap
                        imageData.setPath(principalListOfImages.get(i));//le setteo el path
                        checkIn.getImages().add(imageData);//recupero mi arreglo de objetos y le setteo mi nuevo objeto
                        listOfBitmaps.add(bitmap);//cada BItmap lo setteo al arraylist
                    }//for

                    new UploadImage().execute(listOfBitmaps);
```

> UploadImage.java (AsyncTask)

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {//ejecuta nuestras tareas principales
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {

        CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//hago una instancia de checkin
        JSONObject jsonImage = new JSONObject();//creo un JSONObject

        ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfBitmaps = (ArrayList<Bitmap>) params[0];//Obtengo mi Arreglo de objetos para despues pasarlos a un array lis de Bitmap
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//permitira la salida de los bytes

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfBitmaps.size(); i++) {//itero el arreglo

            listOfBitmaps.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);//se comprime la imagen
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();//codifica el path a un arreglo de byte
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);//codifico ese byteArray a base64 y despues a scrintg

            jsonImage.put("folio", checkIn.getFolio());//paso el folio al JSONObject
            jsonImage.put("images", encoded);//le paso al JSONObject los codigos de las iameges

            StringEntityHC4 entityHC4 = new StringEntityHC4(jsonImage.toString(), ContentType.create("json/application", "UTF-8"));//la direccion del servidor a la que va a apuntar
            HttpPutHC4 httpPutHC4 = new HttpPutHC4(DynamicUrl.BASE_URL + DynamicUrl.SERVER_HOST + ":" + DynamicUrl.SERVER_PORT + "/api/checkkin");//la direccion del dervidor al que va a apuntar

            httpPutHC4.setEntity(entityHC4);//seteo los datos que tengo en el JSONObject

            httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();//La configuracion del servidor va a ser default
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPutHC4);//Obtengo la respuesta del servidor

            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {//si el estatus de la respuesta es igual a 200
                JSONObject jsonRosponse = new JSONObject(EntityUtilsHC4.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));//creo un JSONObject y le paso el JSON que recibio de la sespuesta del servidor

                if (jsonRosponse.getString("code").equals("OK")) {//checo que el JSON tenga la clave OK
                    System.out.println("Las imagenes se guardaron correctamente");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error al subir las imagenes");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
            }
        }//./for
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```